# Столбец определен неоднозначно ORA-00918

Tags: sql, база-данных, plsql, plsql-developer

Имеется маленький кусочек простого селекта

```
select et.control_cost
from metrology.equipment_type et
join metrology.equipment e on e.equipment_type_id = et.id
join metrology.graf_lines t on e.id = t.equ_id
join metrology.graf_shapka gs on gs.id = t.graf_id
join metrology.equipment_type et on et.id = t.equipment_type_id
where gs.pyear = 2016
and et.buro_id = 1
and t.DIC_CONTROL_TYPE_ID = 1
```

Столбцы префиксированы - однако при запросе возникает сообщение ORA-00918:

> "Столбец определен неоднозначно".

Comment: @Mike, напрямую в plsql developer.
Методом пробы установил, что убрав данную строку

join metrology.equipment_type et on et.id = t.equipment_type_id

запрос выполняется. Ничего не понимаю.

Comment: А для чего используется дважды "metrology.equipment_type et"?

Comment: Значит я то же слепой, поискать слона в виде повтора таблицы И алиаса не догадался :)

Comment: P.S. @DmitryKulevich вам намекает, что это строка вообще не нужна, вы уже один `metrology.equipment_type et` используете во второй строке и пытаетесь сделать join с ним же и с тем же алиасом в 6й

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В логику запроса особо не вникал.

Нельзя использовать алиас et для таблиц два раза.

```
metrology.equipment_type et
```

и здесь

```
join metrology.equipment_type et on et.id = t.equipment_type_id
```

Используйте, например,

```
join metrology.equipment_type et2 on et2.id = t.equipment_type_id
```

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, ответ @Fix не совсем правильный (даже почти неправильный). Один и тот же алиас для таблицы использовать два раза можно:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select t.a, t.b from 
(select 1 a from dual) t,
(select 2 b from dual) t;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          2

SQL>
```

Главное - уникальными должны быть названия столбцов. В запросе выше, например, их надо перечислять явно, через `*` он уже не работает:

```
SQL> select * from 
(select 1 a from dual) t,
(select 2 b from dual) t;
select * from
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

SQL>
```

У вас проблема была в том, что вы взяли одну и ту же таблицу 2 раза, а так так столбцы там тоже одинаковые, то СУБД не поняла, что вы от нее хотите. Одну и ту же таблицу можно (а иногда и нужно) джойнить с собой, и вот **в этом случае** алиасы должны быть разные.
Если посмотреть [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2080424), там написано про столбцы следущее:

> If two or more tables have some column names in common, and if you are specifying a join in the FROM clause, then you must qualify column names with names of tables or table aliases.

В то же время в разделе `t_alias` написано:

> Specify a correlation name, which is an alias for the table, view, materialized view, or subquery for evaluating the query. This alias is required if the select list references any object type attributes or object type methods. Correlation names are most often used in a correlated query. Other references to the table, view, or materialized view throughout the query must refer to this alias.

И ни слова про уникальность.